# Entity Framework Mapping Entity To Itself

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity that needs to contain a related entity of itself:

```
public class Period
{
public int ID {get; set;}
public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}  
public Period PriorPeriod {get; set;}  

}
```

How can I achieve this using only POCOs or does this require a Fluent API Mapping?

Comment: What do you want to *achieve*? You are done.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Period
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? PriorPeriodID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriorPeriodID")]
    public Period PriorPeriod { get; set; }
}
```